# Extract first sequence of strings in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, columnsorting

I have a column in a DF as below

```
| Column A       |
| ab, bce, bc    |
| bc, abcd, ab   | 
| ab, cd, abc    |
```

and i want to create a new column that only takes the first sequence, as showed below

```
| Column A       | Column B |
| ab, bce, bc    | ab       |
| bc, abcd, ab   | bc       |
| ab, cd, abc    | ab       |
```

I tried with this code but it only gives me the first letter of the first sequence, not the entire abbrevation

```
df.loc[:, 'ColumnB'] = df.ColumnA.map(lambda x: x[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the items in columnA are strings like e.g. 'ab, bce, bc', so just use split ;).

```
df.loc[:, 'ColumnB'] = df.ColumnA.map(lambda x: x.split(',')[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can alos try vectorised str method split and use integer indexing on the list to get the first element:

```
df['Column B'] = df['Column A'].str.split(',').str[0]
```

Should gives

```
Column A       Column B 
ab, bce, bc    ab       
bc, abcd, ab   bc       
ab, cd, abc    ab
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close, you just need to convert strings to lists with [**`pandas.Series.split`**](https://pandas.Series.str.split) before the map :

```
df["Column B"]= df["Column A"].str.split(",").map(lambda x: x[0])
```

You can also use [**`pandas.Series.get`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) :

```
df["Column B"]= df["Column A"].str.split(",").str.get(0)
```

Another option is list comprehension:

```
df["Column B"]= [el[0] for el in df["Column A"].str.split(",")]
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)

       Column A Column B
0   ab, bce, bc       ab
1  bc, abcd, ab       bc
2   ab, cd, abc       ab
```

Answer (score 1):

So,the row is treated as **string** and you are getting the first index of string "ab,bce,bc".

You need to convert that to a **list** and then take the first element which will be "ab" now.

```
df.loc[:, 'ColumnB'] = df.ColumnA.map(lambda x: x.split(",")[0])
```

This creates "ColumnB" as you require.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first chunk, don't [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html). Instead [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the initial non `,` characters. This will be more efficient:

```
df['Column B'] = df['Column A'].str.extract('([^,]+)')
```

Output:

```
       Column A Column B
0   ab, bce, bc       ab
1  bc, abcd, ab       bc
2   ab, cd, abc       ab
```